# How to convert string elements with single quotes to double quotes in a Python list

Tags: python, preprocessor, python-3.8

I am preprocessing data for an NLP task and need to structure the data in the following way:

> [tokenized_sentence] tab [tags_corresponding_to_tokens]

I have a text file with thousands of lines in this format, where the two lists are separated by a tab. Here is an example

```
['EU', 'rejects', 'German', 'call', 'to', 'boycott', 'British', 'lamb', '.']    ['I-ORG', 'O', 'I-MISC', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'I-MISC', 'O', 'O']
```

and the piece of code I used to get this is

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as foo:
    for i,j in zip(range(len(text)),range(len(tags))):
        foo.write(str([item for item in text[i].split()]) + '\t' + str([tag for tag in tags[j]]) + '\n')
```

where **text** is a list containing sentences (i.e. each sentence is a string) and **tags** is a list of tags (i.e. the tags corresponding to each word/token in a sentence is a list).

I need to get the string elements in the lists to have double quotes instead of single quotes while maintaining this structure. The expected output should look like this

```
["EU", "rejects", "German", "call", "to", "boycott", "British", "lamb", "."]    ["I-ORG",  "O", "I-MISC", "O", "O", "O", "I-MISC", "O", "O"]
```

I've tried using `json.dump()` and `json.dumps()` from the `json` module in Python but I didn't get the expected output as required. Instead, I get the two lists as strings. My best effort was to manually add the double quotes like this (for the tags)

```
for i in range(len(tags)):
    for token in tags[i]:
        tkn = "\"%s\"" %token
        print(tkn)
```

which gives the output

```
"I-ORG"
"O"
"I-MISC"
"O"
"O"
"O"
"I-MISC"
"O"
"O"
"I-PER"
"I-PER"
.
.
.
```

however, this seems too inefficient. I have seen these related questions

- [Convert single-quoted string to double-quoted string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906991/convert-single-quoted-string-to-double-quoted-string)
- [Converting a Text file to JSON format using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482614/converting-a-text-file-to-json-format-using-python)

but they didn't address this directly.

I'm using Python 3.8

Comment: if the words doesn't contain quotes you can simply use `replace("'", '"')`

Comment: @deadshot I tried this `tags[0][0].replace("'",'"')`  and the output did not change. I still get string elements with single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no way to force python to write strings with double quotes; the default is single quotes. As @deadshot commented, you can either replace the `'` with `"` after you write the whole string to the file, or manually add the double quotes when you write each word. The answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056548/printing-double-quotes-around-a-variable/20056615) post has many different ways to do it, the simplest being `f'"{your_string_here}"'`. You would need to write each string separately though, as writing a list automatically adds `'` around every item, and that would be very spaghetti.

Just do `find and replace ' with "` after you write the string to the file.

You can even do it with python:

```py
# after the string is written in 'data.txt'
with open('data.txt', "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

text = text.replace("'", '"')

with open('data.txt', "w") as f:
    text = f.write(text)
```

---

### Edit according to OP's comment below

Do this instead of the above; this should fix most of the problems, as it searches for the string `', '` which, hopefully, only appears at the end of one string and the start of the next

```py
with open('data.txt', "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

# replace ' at the start of the list
text = text.replace("['", '["')

# replace ' at the end of the list
text = text.replace("']", '"]')

# replace ' at the item changes inside the list
text = text.replace("', '", '", "')

with open('data.txt', "w") as f:
    text = f.write(text)
```

---

### (Edit by OP) New edit based on my latest comment

Running this solves the problem I described in the comment and returns the expected solution.

```py
with open('data.txt', "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

# replace ' at the start of the list
text = text.replace("['", '["')

# replace ' at the end of the list
text = text.replace("']", '"]')

# replace ' at the item changes inside the list
text = text.replace("', '", '", "')

text = text.replace("', ", '", ')

text = text.replace(", '", ', "')

with open('data.txt', "w") as f:
    text = f.write(text)
```

Comment: This solves my problem, thank you! I realized though that it brings about another problem I did not anticipate, where apostrophes and phrases with quotes in the original text get replaced with `"`. But I will find a way to workaround this.

Comment: Ah my bad, I overlooked that. As long as any string inside the text doesn't contain the pattern `', '` (found at the end of one string and the start of the next) it should work fine.

Comment: Your latest edit solved the apostrophe problem. In some cases though it removed double quotes, for example, `[ "Germany", ""s", "representative", ...]` became `["Germany', "'s", 'representative", ...]`. However, this was not a big problem and I quickly fixed it by adding two lines to your proposed solution.